# Application of the inverse theorem function on singular points

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

This question is related to this one [A question about the inverse theorem function in $\mathbb{R}^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140207/a-question-about-the-inverse-theorem-function-in-mathbbrn). In the response I received, I was told that the issue was related to the singularities, as I do not have a strong background in this area, I'll ask the question again stating exactly the situation.

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $\eta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the familly $(A^{n-1}\eta,\ldots,\eta)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. We define the mapping
\begin{equation*}
   \begin{matrix}
   G_{\eta}
   \quad : \quad&\mathbb{R}^{n}&\rightarrow&\mathbb{R}^{n}\\
                    &  (t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})  &\mapsto &\prod_{i=1}^{n}(A+t_{i}I)\eta
   \end{matrix}.
\end{equation*}

$G_{\eta}$ is continuously differentiable and  one can  readily see that the jacobian determinant of $G_{\eta}$ is given by
 $$\mid\frac{\partial G_{\eta}(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n})}{\partial(t_{1},\ldots,t_{n})}|=
  \mathrm{det}(A^{n-1}\eta,\quad A^{n-2}\eta,\quad\ldots\quad ,\eta)V(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n}),$$
where $V(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})=\displaystyle\prod_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(t_i-t_j)$.

Then for $(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $V(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})\neq0$, we have from the Inverse theorem function the existence of a neighborhood V of $(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $G_{\eta}(V)$ is a neighborhood of $G_{\eta}(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. I wonder if this reamain true even for $(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $V(t_{1},\cdots,t_{n})=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Near any point where $V$ has a zero of order 1, i.e. a point where precisely two of the $t_i$ are equal, the map looks like a fold singularity, so doesn't have any such neighborhood. It looks like $(x,y,\dots) \mapsto (x^2,y,\dots)$. I think you can find everything you need in [this nice introduction](http://www.sissa.it/fa/download/publications/remizov.pdf)